# Exclamation Unary operator stopped working on bindings

Tags: extjs6

This used to work in previous versions of ExtJS

```
bind: {
    disabled: '{!my-grid.selection}'
},
```

The

In version 6.2 does not work anymore. How can solve this?

OR is there a way to do it the opposite way:

```
bind: {
        enabled: '{my-grid.selection}'
    },
```

Thanks.

I found that grid.getView().getSelectionModel().isSelected() returns always false, even if row is selected.
grid.getView().getSelectionModel().selected returns the selected row, so I made sure the row is actually selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the name. In 6.2+ it introduced various enhancements to the binding syntax to allow for expressions. In this case, the `'-'` character is being interpreted as a minus. Try using an underscore, or just camel casing for the name.